# 1TB Caviar Green no longer detected after BIOS upgrade

Tags: hard-drive, bios

Just after I upgraded my BIOS, I enjoyed a constant black screen after the BIOS Screen, which said something like CTRL + ALT + DELETE to reboot. It was no longer detecting something. So I removed the second HD and I was able to boot windows.

During the next boot I did the trick to connect the hard drive to the mobo during the Windows loading screen. And the HD became recognized, I was able to use it normally. In the next boot I left the hard rive connected and it wasn't detected by BIOS or Windows. I tried several cable combinations to see if there's a faulty one but no avail.

The weird part is that this drive does not emit any particular sound and most of faulty drives make noises. Another strange thing is that with the power supply connected the hard drive gets hot, really hot, like it's doing something...

Maybe I should downgrade the BIOS if I can. What do you think?

MOBO: Asrock 4g1m VS3.
PSU: 600W generic.
Western Digital Caviar Green 1 TB SATA (Like 5 months old)

Comment: "with the power supply connected the hard drive gets hot, really hot, like it's doing something..."  There's your first sign that something is wrong, really wrong...  Since there's no sound, coupled with the extreme rise in temperature, it's possible that something is mechanically seized in the drive, blocking the drive spindle from moving (thus shorting out the motor).  Have you tried the drive in an external enclosure or in another computer?

Comment: @Breakthrough " I did the trick to connect the hard drive to the mobo during the Windows loading screen. And the HD became recognized, I was able to use it normally" apparently it is working.

Comment: I would load bios default settings, save changes on exit of bios, see if this helps.

Comment: @Moab if the hard drive is not consistently detected, I just figured it would be wise to at least *try* the thing in an alternate computer.  There's no other way to determine the root cause (whether it be the motherboard or the hard drive) of the issue otherwise.

Comment: I just tested in other motherboard, bios or windows won't detect the drive, it does not make clicking noises, and it does spin, I didn't have much time to test it but it wasn't as hot as it was on my computer.

Comment: I Cleared the CMOS and realized that the drive is not spinning but only vibrating slightly by the power current. The heat is near 90C, and I think we are going nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver was damaged beyond repair. With high enough temperature you could fry eggs with.